# JQuery not responding to a POST request

Tags: jquery, laravel

i'm working with Laravel and JQuery, I've set up a form and the controller instructions for it to store information in the database, now the problem is that after being all set up when i click the "submit" button, nothing happens, i always keep the console open to check for errors and to see the requests, but now it's not doing anything.

Here is the code:

On the header i added this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

my form looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" style="margin-top: -5px;">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" style="margin-top: -5px;">Summary</label>
        <textarea id="summary" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" style="margin-top: -5px;">Description</label>
        <textarea id="description" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" style="margin-top: -5px;">Link to media (optional)</label>
        <input id="medialink" class="form-control" type="text" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg full-width" type="button" id="ajaxSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
public function submitit($id, Request $request)
{
    $bounty = Bounty::where('id', $id)->first();
    $vulnerability = new Vulnerability();
    $vulnerability->title = $request->title;
    $vulnerability->summary = $request->summary;
    $vulnerability->description = $request->description;
    $vulnerability->medialink = $request->media;
    $vulnerability->save();
    Toastr::success('Successfuly submitted', 'Congratulations!', ['toast-top-right']);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Submitted correctly']);
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
               jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "{{ url('/submitit/' . $bounty->id . '/' . $bounty->company_identifier) }}",
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {
                     _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                     title: jQuery('#title').val(),
                     summary: jQuery('#summary').val(),
                     description: jQuery('#description').val(),
                     medialink: jQuery('#medialink').val()
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                     console.log(result);
                  }});
               });
            });

</script>
```

in my route i got:

```
Route::post('/submitit/{id}', [

'uses' => 'BountyController@submitit',

])->middleware('auth');
```

What's going on? why is it not sending any request?

Comment: Show us jquery (Ajax) code of submitting the form plz.

Comment: Sorry, just added it :)

Comment: Have you tried calling the post method using postman or curl?

Comment: Try to add `console.log('something')` before the `$.ajaxSetup({` row and click the button to see, whether the click-event is fired.

Comment: Add some error handling and inspect the xhr object for clues. Or inspect actual request in browser dev tools network. And you can't send anything else other than json. Get rid of the server side Toastr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, i did not notice that the route on the `ajax` was not matching the one in the `web.php` file.

solution was to change this: `url: "{{ url('/submitit/' . $bounty->id . '/' . $bounty->company_identifier) }}",`

to this: `url: "{{ url('/submitit/' . $bounty->id) }}",`

Answer (score 0):

You change url

```
 url: "{{ url('/submitit/' . $bounty->id . '/' . $bounty->company_identifier) }}",
```

to

```
 url: "{{ action('BountyController@submitit', ['id' => $bounty->id]) }}",
```

and then you dump in Controller or F12 open tab Network see request send

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  jquery ajax 
>       url: "{{ url('/submitit/' . $bounty->id . '/' . $bounty->company_identifier) }}"
> ```

```
   write In route url like

   Route::post('/submitit/{id}/{company_identifier}',
      'BountyController@submitit')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `Type` instead of `method` in ajax setting object.

More on the answer:
As you are setting

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
   }
```

You don't need `_token` in your `data` field.
Try to add this section to your ajax setting object so that you can see if there is any error response.

```
error: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
```

Comment: still does not do anything

Comment: `_token` may not be necessary, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DanielLogvin First, see if `click` event is triggered or not by putting a `consle.log('test');` inside click event of the element.

Comment: when i do the `error:` part i get: `esponseJSON: Object { exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",` thing is that when i submit it without jquery it does stores the information and finds the routes.